# wxPython: How to remove slider and in return populate custom gauge with function CpuData

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to Python and have been following along with some wxPython tutorials online and was wondering how I could populate my custom cpu gauge with actual data!

Currently the custom gauge gets its value/data from a slider widget that the user has to manual drag up or down.

I wrote a simple function named: CpuData() which will basically return a dummy CPU value ranging from 0 to 100.

Now the question I have is how do I eliminate the Slider and have my gauge automatically get populated by looping through the CpuData() function.

Sorry for the Newbie question!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Current Custom Gauge Layout]

```
import wx
import random


def CpuData():      # Will return a random CPU value
cData = random.randint(0,100)
print cData

CpuData()

class CPU(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, size=(80, 110))

        self.parent = parent

        self.SetBackgroundColour('#000000')


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)


    def OnPaint(self, event):

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)

        dc.SetDeviceOrigin(0, 100)
        dc.SetAxisOrientation(True, True)

        pos = self.parent.GetParent().GetParent().sel
        rect = pos / 5

        for i in range(1, 21):
            if i > rect:
                dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#075100'))
                dc.DrawRectangle(10, i*4, 30, 5)
                dc.DrawRectangle(41, i*4, 30, 5)
            else:
                dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#36ff27'))
                dc.DrawRectangle(10, i*4, 30, 5)
                dc.DrawRectangle(41, i*4, 30, 5)


class CPUWidget(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(190, 140))

        self.sel = 0

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        centerPanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1)

        self.cpu = CPU(centerPanel, -1)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.slider = wx.Slider(panel, -1, self.sel, 0, 100, (-1, -1), (25, 90), 
    wx.VERTICAL | wx.SL_LABELS | wx.SL_INVERSE)
        self.slider.SetFocus()

        hbox.Add(centerPanel, 0,  wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 20)
        hbox.Add(self.slider, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 23)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnScroll)

        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


    def OnScroll(self, event):
        self.sel = event.GetInt()
        self.cpu.Refresh()

app = wx.App()
CPUWidget(None, -1, 'cpu')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, this code works by a timer calling a function that triggers a custom event to generate a new value and update the CPU Graph.

The timer is provided by wxpython however any timing function would work (eg: a thread running a sleep function).

In this specific example, a custom event is not necessary as the timer is provided by the GUI itself. Nonetheless, using events is a good practice to get into as it allows a more abstract implementation (allowing easier refactoring) and eliminates threading issues when data is generated by non-GUI threads.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

import random

CpuEvent, EVT_CPU_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class CPU(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, size=(80, 110))

        self.value  = 100
        self.parent = parent

        self.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(EVT_CPU_EVENT, self.do_value)

    def do_value(self, event):
        self.value = event.value
        self.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, event):

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)

        dc.SetDeviceOrigin(0, 100)
        dc.SetAxisOrientation(True, True)

        pos = self.value
        rect = pos / 5

        for i in range(1, 21):
            if i > rect:
                dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#075100'))
                dc.DrawRectangle(10, i*4, 30, 5)
                dc.DrawRectangle(41, i*4, 30, 5)
            else:
                dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#36ff27'))
                dc.DrawRectangle(10, i*4, 30, 5)
                dc.DrawRectangle(41, i*4, 30, 5)


class CPUWidget(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.cpu = CPU(self, -1)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.do_CpuData)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.cpu, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(hbox)
        hbox.Fit(self)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)
        self.timer.Start(1000)

    def do_CpuData(self, event = None):
        cData = random.randint(0, 100)
        event = CpuEvent(value = cData)
        wx.PostEvent(self.cpu, event)

app = wx.App(redirect = False)
CPUWidget(None, -1, 'cpu')
app.MainLoop()
```